# How to get rid of extra rows?

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is the tables structure I have:

[image]

1) When I use this query:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID--, T_TicketPrint.TicketBarCode
FROM       T_ActionTicketLog LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
      --LEFT OUTER JOIN T_TicketPrint ON T_OrderTicket.ActionTicketID = T_TicketPrint.ActionTicketID and T_OrderTicket.ID = T_TicketPrint.OrderTicketID
where T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 24014999
```

Everything works fine and looks as following:

[image]

2) But, when I use this query because I need T_TicketPrint.TicketBarCode:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID, T_TicketPrint.TicketBarCode
FROM       T_ActionTicketLog LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN T_TicketPrint ON T_OrderTicket.ActionTicketID = T_TicketPrint.ActionTicketID and T_OrderTicket.ID = T_TicketPrint.OrderTicketID
where T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 24014999
```

I've got the extra rows and it looks as following:

[image]

How to get rid of extra rows?

The desired result:

[image]

Comment: by extra rows, you mean rows containing null ?

Comment: You are getting for one actionTicket several barcodes. Which of them do you want?

Comment: In wrong result screen shot, everything is fine until rows number 9. After that, the statuses are repeating 3 times, which is wrong. The sequence of statuses should be as in correct screen shot.

Comment: The problem is in Print table, you have several prints for action 2 for example with different barcodes. Which of these barcodes do you want in output?

Comment: Even T_TicketStatus table is not necessary. I've updated the queries.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting multiple records as there are multiple barcodes for each status. In case you want to get latest one, and I presume highest number is latest then aggregating third table will help:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID, 

max(T_TicketPrint.TicketBarCode)
FROM       T_ActionTicketLog INNER JOIN T_TicketStatus ON T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID = T_TicketStatus.ID
           LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
           LEFT OUTER JOIN T_TicketPrint ON T_OrderTicket.ActionTicketID = T_TicketPrint.ActionTicketID and T_OrderTicket.ID = T_TicketPrint.OrderTicketID
group by T_TicketPrint.ActionTicketID
where T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 24014999
```

Comment: That's what I want to avoid because we need 3 different bar codes for each status sequence that contains status 3. It means the first bar code - 197797471545 should repeat 3 times: rows number 10, 11, 12. The second bar code - 197797473537 should appear 3 times: rows 13, 14, 15. The third bar code - 197797476671 should appear 3 times: rows 16, 17, 18.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just any one of BarCode then you can do:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID ,
        T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID ,
        oa.TicketBarCode
FROM    T_ActionTicketLog
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                *
                      FROM      T_TicketPrint
                      WHERE     T_OrderTicket.ActionTicketID = T_TicketPrint.ActionTicketID
                                AND T_OrderTicket.ID = T_TicketPrint.OrderTicketID
                      ORDER BY  BarCode
                    ) oa
WHERE   T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 24014999
```

All BarCodes in one column:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID ,
        T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID ,
        oa.TicketBarCode
FROM    T_ActionTicketLog
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    STUFF((SELECT   ',' + TicketBarCode
                                       FROM     T_TicketPrint
                                       WHERE    T_OrderTicket.ActionTicketID = T_TicketPrint.ActionTicketID
                                                AND T_OrderTicket.ID = T_TicketPrint.OrderTicketID
                                FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                                          TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,
                                      1, '') AS TicketBarCode
                    ) oa
WHERE   T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 24014999
```

Comment: We need 3 different bar codes for each status sequence that contains status 3. It means the first bar - 197797471545 code should repeat 3 times: rows number 10, 11, 12. The second bar code - 197797473537 should appear 3 times: rows 13, 14, 15. The third bar code - 197797476671 should appear 3 times: rows 16, 17, 18.

Comment: I don't need that. Please, take a look at update of my comment above.

Comment: The status 3 means - sold. Each sell has its own bar code.

Comment: And what about rows 19, 20, 21...? Which BarCodes should be there?
Also why 197797471545 should be repeated for status = 2 and 197797473537 for status = 3 and not vice verse? You are not providing enough info don't you think? Paste the desired result screenshot and describe the logic behind.

Comment: There should be 18 rows as in first table. The second table with 36 rows is incorrect. As I wrote, there are extra rows.

Comment: The issue is I can't get desired result.

Comment: I can not help you without seeing test data and desired output

Comment: Ok. I've tried to draw the desired result. Please, take a look at new screen shot in the original post.

Comment: Try to answer:  why 197797471545 should be repeated for status = 2 and 197797473537 for status = 3 and not the other way round?

Comment: Actually, the status 2 is not important. The important are the statuses 3 and 10 only.

Comment: Here we have the sold tickets in T_TicketPrint table. When the ticket is sold it can be printed out. The important things is when we print the ticket, every time new bar code is generated. In this case we have a ticket that was sold and printed out 3 times with 3 different bar codes.