# How to get rid of repeated rows?

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is the tables structure I have:

[image]

1) When I use this query:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID
      --,case when (dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID <> 2 and dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID <> 6) then dbo.T_TicketPrint.TicketBarCode
      --else null end as TicketBarCode
FROM       T_ActionTicketLog
      LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
      --LEFT OUTER JOIN T_TicketPrint ON T_OrderTicket.ActionTicketID = T_TicketPrint.ActionTicketID and T_OrderTicket.ID = T_TicketPrint.OrderTicketID
where T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 24014999
```

Everything works fine and looks as following:

[image]

2) But, when I use this query because I need T_TicketPrint.TicketBarCode:

```
SELECT  T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID
      ,case when (dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID <> 2 and dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID <> 6) then dbo.T_TicketPrint.TicketBarCode
      else null end as TicketBarCode
FROM       T_ActionTicketLog
      LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN T_TicketPrint ON T_OrderTicket.ActionTicketID = T_TicketPrint.ActionTicketID and T_OrderTicket.ID = T_TicketPrint.OrderTicketID
where T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = 24014999
```

I've got the extra rows and it looks as following:

[image]

Here we have the sold tickets in T_TicketPrint table. When the ticket is sold (status 3) it can be printed out (status 10). The important thing is when we print the ticket, every time new bar code is generated. In this case we have a ticket that was sold and printed out 3 times with 3 different bar codes.

The desired result (other values in TicketBarCode column should be NULL):

[image]

How to get rid of extra rows?

This is final correct script:

;WITH cte1
AS (SELECT T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID, T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID, T_ActionTicketLog.Created,
CASE WHEN StatusID IN (3, 10) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
* ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID ORDER BY T_ActionTicketLog.Created ) AS rn
FROM T_ActionTicketLog
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
),
cte2
AS ( SELECT ActionTicketID , OrderTicketID, TicketBarCode,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ActionTicketID ORDER BY Created ) AS rn
FROM T_TicketPrint
)
SELECT c1.ActionTicketID, c1.StatusID , oa.TicketBarCode
FROM cte1 c1
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT *
FROM cte2 c2
WHERE c1.ActionTicketID = c2.ActionTicketID AND c1.TicketOrderID = c2.OrderTicketID AND c1.rn = c2.rn
) oa
where c1.ActionTicketID = 24014999
order by c1.Created

Comment: have you tried adding `AND (dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID = 3 or dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID = 10)` to your second `JOIN` ?

Comment: @tesicg, answer questions which we ask you rather than opening new questions. I repeat my question: why on line 11, 12 there is 197797471545 and on lines 14, 15 197797473537? Why it not the other way round? 11, 12 197797473537; 14, 15 197797471545? What is the logic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of extra rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250135/how-to-get-rid-of-extra-rows)

Comment: @stb: In that case the statuses 2 and 6 don't repeat, which is fine, but 3 and 10 are still repeating.

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri: It's better explained here.

Comment: can you provide create scripts of your tables with inserts where we can see real data?And answer my question at last

Comment: Well, they repeat because you have multiple barcodes. It's your turn to decide, which one(s) you need

Comment: @stb: I need the bar codes from the last screen shot, which means first bar code should for first pair of statuses 3 and 10, second bar code should for second pair of statuses 3 and 10 and third bar code should for third pair of statuses 3 and 10.

Comment: I can't provide the script of the tables because there are sensitive data. The data from screen shots are real as well.

Comment: I've tried to delete my first question "How to get rid of extra rows?" because it's not so clear, but I'm unable to do it because the system doesn't allow it.

Comment: `first bar code should for first pair of statuses 3 and 10, second bar code should for second pair of statuses 3 and 10 and third bar code should for third pair of statuses 3 and 10`. This is what I have asked you 5 times. The logic behind choosing those barcodes

Comment: I've drawn that in the last screen shot... So, you got it now?

Comment: I think yes, if I have N pairs of status (3,10) in log, there would be N bar codes in prints?

Comment: Yes. We can reprint the same ticket and every time we got new bar code. The bar codes are generated in ascending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right you need to apply to first pair of(3, 10) the first barcode, second barcode to second pair and so on. But it is not clear which of these pairs is first or second.

This is test script:

```
DECLARE @actions TABLE
    (
      TicketID INT ,
      StatusID INT
    )
DECLARE @prints TABLE
    (
      TicketID INT ,
      BarCode NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT  INTO @actions
VALUES  ( 1, 2 ),
        ( 1, 4 ),
        ( 1, 3 ),
        ( 1, 10 ),
        ( 1, 6 ),
        ( 1, 3 ),
        ( 1, 10 ),
        ( 1, 6 ),
        ( 1, 3 ),
        ( 1, 10 ),
        ( 1, 6 ),
        ( 1, 7 )


INSERT  INTO @prints
VALUES  ( 1, 'C1' ),
        ( 1, 'C2' ),
        ( 1, 'C3' );
WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        CASE WHEN StatusID IN ( 3, 10 ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END
                        * ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY TicketID, StatusID ORDER BY StatusID ) AS rn
               FROM     @actions a
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY TicketID ORDER BY BarCode ) AS rn
               FROM     @prints a
             )
    SELECT  c1.TicketID ,
            c1.StatusID ,
            oa.BarCode
    FROM    cte1 c1
            OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    *
                          FROM      cte2 c2
                          WHERE     c1.TicketID = c2.TicketID
                                    AND c1.rn = c2.rn
                        ) oa
```

Ouptut:

```
TicketID    StatusID    BarCode
1           2           NULL
1           3           C1
1           3           C2
1           3           C3
1           4           NULL
1           6           NULL
1           6           NULL
1           6           NULL
1           7           NULL
1           10          C1
1           10          C2
1           10          C3
```

Something like:

```
;WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT    T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.OrderTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID ,
                        CASE WHEN StatusID IN ( 3, 10 ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END
                        * ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID ORDER BY T_ActionTicketLog.Created ) AS rn
               FROM       T_ActionTicketLog
               LEFT OUTER JOIN T_OrderTicket ON T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = T_OrderTicket.ID
             ),

    cte2
      AS ( SELECT   ActionTicketID , OrderTicketID, TicketBarCode
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ActionTicketID ORDER BY Created ) AS rn
           FROM     T_TicketPrint
         )
SELECT  c1.ActionTicketID, c1.StatusID , oa.TicketBarCode
FROM    cte1 c1
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    *
                      FROM      cte2 c2
                      WHERE     c1.ActionTicketID = c2.ActionTicketID AND c1.ID = c2.OrderTicketID AND c1.rn = c2.rn
                    ) oa
```

Comment: There's a lot of errors in last script. I'm not able to run it. And where can I put the condition: ActionTicketID = 24014999?

Comment: You didn't provide any table structures. I was writing that code with closed eyes. What did you expect? Try to correct errors. Or write here those errors. We are not vangas. You can put it int the very end. `WHERE c1.ActionTicketID = 24014999`

Comment: Please, take a look at the original post what I correct.

Comment: What did you correct? I see no changes. I am done here

Comment: I did some changes. Everything is above.

Comment: see my edits, `SELECT  c1.ActionTicketID, c1.StatusID , oa.TicketBarCode
    FROM    cte1 c1
            OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    *
                          FROM      cte2 c2
                          WHERE     c1.ActionTicketID = c2.ActionTicketID AND c1.ID = c2.OrderTicketID AND c1.rn = c2.rn
                        ) oa`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73766/discussion-between-giorgi-nakeuri-and-tesicg).

Comment: There's one more question in chat.